# A bit confused with promises/chained functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, promise

I'm still trying to get my head around all this and I'm obviously missing some fundamental concepts.

In my code I have a scenario whereby I want to call several functions in a row and when they've all completed, wrap it up with a finishing routine where subtotals are calculated and a pie chart is updated.

Although the functions I call themselves aren't asynchronous, they do contain ajax calls which are, hence why I want to wait for all of them to finish before I calculate totals and update the chart.

So I tried doing:

```
    var fnArray= [];
    fnArray.push(genericCalc("use_", true, false, false));
    fnArray.push(doArticleImpacts(false));
    fnArray.push(genericProjectCalc("tpD2C_", false, false));
    fnArray.push(genericCalc("eol_", true, false, false));
    fnArray.push(calcPackaging(false));

    var calcPromise = Q.all(fnArray);

    return calcPromise
            .then(calcsDone)
            .fail(calcsFailed);

    function calcsDone() {
        calcTotals(); 
        setChart(selectedRow());
    }

    function calcsFailed() {
        logger.logError("Failure in calculations", "", null, true);
    }
```

...but using the above code and using the script debugger with a stop on the "return calcPromise" line, the fnArray is set to "0:undefined, 1:undefined, 2:Object, 3:undefined, 4:Promise" even before the promise is activated.

I understand that this is obviously something to do with my functions, but I don't really understand what I need to do differently. The functions all vary slightly, but are fundamentally something like:

```
var genericCalc = function (calcPrefix) {
    var res_Array = ko.observable(); //holds returned results
    prjArticleArray.forEach(function (thisArticle) {

        var calcPromise = calcEOL(res_Array, thisArticle);  //another function containing async ajax call

        return calcPromise
                .then(calcsDone)
                .fail(calcsFailed);

        function calcsDone() {
            //do calculation subtotals here and set a knockout observable value
        }

        function calcsFailed() {
            logger.logError("Failure in " + calcPrefix + "calculation", "", null, true);
        }

    });
};
```

What is it that makes some of the functions "undefined", some "object" and some "promise" in my array that I want to use for Q.all?  Do I have to have "Q.resolve" in the "calcsDone" part of the functions I'm calling?

I've seen other questions/answers on stackoverflow along similar lines, but they seem to always be calls directly to async calls and my fist level functions I'm stacking up in the promise aren't... should I not be using this structure for non-async calls or just add "setTimeout" to my function calls to make them async?

Comment: Your `genericCalc` function doesn't return anything. So it will always be undefined in `fnArray`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that this is obviously something to do with my functions, but I don't really understand what I need to do differently

You need to `return` promises from them. Your current `genericCalc` function does not even contain a `return` statement (only the `forEach` callback function inside it does), so it does return `undefined`.

If you need to wait for the result of each article, use `Q.all` like you have already done with `fnArray` (which is a `promiseArray` actually). In `genericCalc` it should look like this:

```
var genericCalc = function (calcPrefix) {
    return Q.all(prjArticleArray.map(function (thisArticle) {
        var calcPromise = calcEOL(res_Array, thisArticle);  //another function containing async ajax call
        var result = calcPromise
                .then(calcsDone)
                .fail(calcsFailed);
        return result;
        …
    });
};
```

> ```
> var res_Array = ko.observable(); //holds returned results
> …
> //do calculation subtotals here and set a knockout observable value
> ```

That is a bad idea. You should not use global variables that are set somewhen and use promises just for propagating changes, but the promises should *represent* these values. This leads to a better, functional programming style.

So instead of setting a global variable, do `return` the result from your `calcsDone` function, and it will resolve the `result` promise with that value.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to get my head around this... so in the code that CALLS the genericCalc function do I need to have something like `var myVar = genericCalc(params...)` or how else does the value get back?  I don't understand your line, "it will resolve the result promise with that value" sorry... (by the way, the observables are entity objects created by Breezejs, I'm not setting up a whole lot of observables manually)

Comment: You can access the value in the `then` callback: `genericCalc(params).then(function(articleResults){…})`. Instead of manually `.resolve()`ing a deferred, it is enough to `return` the value from the `then` callbacks to access it in the next one. The observables are probably needed for your breeze infrastructure, so you might not completely omit them (however, I don't know much about them). My point was that you shouldn't use a global structure to store values in one procedure and to access them from the next one, but that you should pass the results [only] through the promise resolve values.

Comment: I'm not getting it, sorry. This is too far removed from my traditional .net knowledge so it's a mystery. Is there an online resource you could possibly point me at that would help me get a better fundamental understanding do you think please?  I never seem to be able to find any relevant examples when I look.

Comment: I just found https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/General-Promise-Resources, which seems to be an excellent start. If they had not been in that list already, I'd have linked you the two top entries from the "blog posts" section :-)