# More problems with promises

Tags: javascript, promise, q

In my previous question I thought I'd got it sorted, but I've found an intermittent edge condition where the "then" part is being carried out before all the promises resolve in the  `Q.all` call.

Simply, I have the following set up where a generic calculation is called multiple times with different parameters: (code simplified a bit to remove irrelevant code and actual parameter names)

```
    var promiseArray = [];
    promiseArray.push(genericCalc(param1, param2, param3));
    promiseArray.push(genericCalc(param1, param2, param3));
    promiseArray.push(genericCalc(param1, param2, param3));

    var calcPromise = Q.all(promiseArray);

    return calcPromise
            .then(calcsDone)
            .fail(calcsFailed);

    function calcsDone(res) {
        calcTotals(); 
        setChart(selectedRow());
        console.log("done recalculation routine");
    }

    function calcsFailed() {
        logger.logError("Failure in Calculations", "", null, true);
    }
```

genericCalc (with some irrelevant code removed)

```
var genericCalc = function (param1, param2, param3) {

    //specific calculation is determined using parameters passed in and varies but is same structure for each as below
    calcPromise = specificCalc(params...);

    return calcPromise
       .then(calcsDone)
       .fail(calcsFailed);

    function calcsDone(res) {  
      //some minor subtotalling in here using "res" and flag setting             
      return Q.resolve();
    }

    function calcsFailed() {
       //handle error....
    }
};
```

There are 3 or 4 different specific calculations and they all have roughly the same sort of layout:

```
function specificCalc1(params...) {

    var promise = calcContext.ajaxCalc(params);

    return promise
            .then(calcsDone)
            .fail(calcsFailed);

    function calcsDone(res) {
        rv(res);
        console.log("done specific calc 1");
        return Q.resolve();
    }
    function calcsFailed() {
        logger.logError("Failure in specific calc 1", "", null, true);
        return Q.resolve();
    }
};
```

Now I know that this is not a great idea to push the result of the ajax calc into a return value, but at present I don't want to change this as there is just too much code change involved and I feel that, even if not the best methodology at present, this is a learning curve for me and I'll address that part once I have my head around this strange edge condition.

So... what throws me is that every now and again when I change some values on screen which trigger a recalculation, one of the "done" console log messages from one of the specific calcs appears AFTER the "done recalculation routine" one from the first section!

I thought it was being caused by a poorly-constructed promise leading to the function being executed immediately, but the REALLY weird thing is that when I put a debug stop in the server code for that calculation, all works correctly and the client browser is paused until the server code is continued and then the client side debugs show that the next points are being hit.

9 times out of 10 it all works perfectly.  On the 10th one, I see "done recalculation routine" in the console immediately followed by "done specific calc 2" and this causes the totals to be wrong.

I cannot see how this can be happening. I've artificially put time delay loops in all the specific calc functions to make them take several seconds and never once do I see the out of sequence debug messages, but when there is no artificial slowdown in place, I see it 1 in 10 times approximately.

Please would someone try and put me out of my misery here... I just want to know I can rely on the "Q.all" call working in the first block of code, such that when it hits "calcsDone" it has ALWAYS done the generic and specific calcs!

Edit 1:
To explain the "rv" or returnvalue a bit. In "genericCalc", I declare an observable:

```
    var res = ko.observable(); //holds returned results
```

And as part of the call to "specificCalc" I pass that return value in, for example:

```
calcPromise = specificCalc1(isPackaging, res, thisArticle);
```

In the specificCalc I just put the ajax result into the observable, so it is available in "calcsDone" in "genericCalc" and, once all calcs are completed from the "Q.all()" function, the calculation routines can tot up the individual results from each specific Calc.

Edit 2
The console log, when it goes wrong is:

```
done specificCalc1 
done specificCalc2, isPackaging=true 
Done specificCalc3, redraw = false 
done calctotals 
chart replotted 
done recalculation routine
done specificCalc2, isPackaging=false
```

...you can see the "done specificCalc2" after "done recalculation routine" there.

**Edit 3**

I reduced the promiseArray to just one item to check, using the parameters for what seems to be the troublesome call (specificCalc2):

```
var promiseArray = [];
promiseArray.push(genericCalc(param1, param2, param3));
```

And then I put a stop point in the server code.

The result is that the stop in the server code happens and the console already says "done" so it's a problem with the promise construction after all and was somehow being masked by one of the other calls being done. Once I release the stop in server code, I get my console messages from the ajax call function AND the generic Calc  function saying "done".

So, it appears to me as if the problem is in the main Q.all call from what I can tell, as that doesn't wait for the generic calc function being completed before it carries on with its "calcsDone" function.

I just tried returning the genericCalc promise:

```
return genericCalc("eol_", true, false, false)
//return calcPromise
        .then(calcsDone)
        .fail(calcsFailed);
```

...and it instantly fails with "cannot call method "then" of undefined, thus confirming my problem is in the generic calc function, so off to look at that now.

**Edit 4**

Narrowed the problem down to a further function call within genericCalc.  As part of the calculation, this calls a function to remove the impact value as stands before the calculation is done. When the calculation returns it then adds the result back in to the overall amount.

If I "return Q.resolve()" from genericCalc on the line before I do:

```
impactRemove(currentPrefix, currentArticle); //remove impacts for this prefix
```

then the promise works, if I do it on the line after, it fails. So for some reason calling that function seems to resolve the promise. Investigating further now.

**Edit 5**
So the problem is caused when I call a standard function midway through the genericCalc routine. The logic behind this is:

1. Change on browser form retriggers calculation
2. Function is called that sets up array of promises (several of which call the same function with different parameters)
3. Inside that generic function (genericCalc) I call a standard non-promise function that removes the current calculation totals from the project total
4. Calculation is complete
5. Standard non-promise function called to add results of calculation back to project total
6. GenericCalc returns promise to main function
7. Overall totals updated with latest project totals, graphics are updated

What actually seems to happen is that when I call the standard javascript functions with genericCalc, they execute immediately, therefore resolving the promise and although the ajax call is still done, the Q.all call does not wait as it believes the promise is resolved as "genericCalc" is returning "undefined" and not a promise.

At this point, Bergi is screaming at me about my hideous anti-pattern noob coding and I tend to agree with him. Trouble is, I'd like to get it working this way so I have something to test against when I finally adapt it to work correctly.

So... if I have two functions called from within "genericCalc" like so:

```
impactRemove(currentPrefix, currentArticle); //remove impacts for this prefix
```

and

```
impactAdd(currentPrefix, currentArticle); //addimpacts for this prefix
```

Which are basically like this:

```
function impactAdd(prefix, prjArt) {
    if (!prjArt) {return} //just get out as there's nothing to calculate
    factorArray.forEach(function (f) {
        var orig_projValue = pGlobalVar.editProject()[prefix + f]();
        var new_projArtValue = prjArt[prefix + f](); //must be set first!
        pGlobalVar.editProject()[prefix + f](orig_projValue + new_projArtValue); //add new value back in to project value
    });
}
```

...then how do I call these "midpoint" functions within the promise of genericCalc so that I Can still return a promise when a) impactRemove has been completed, b) the remote ajax call has been completed and c) the impactAdd function has been completed?

Do I need to set up code within genericCalc to do something like:

```
impactRemove(params...).then(<ajax function that returns new calculation results>).then(impactAdd(params))
```

...or will (params) after my functions automatically invoke those functions, thus resolving the promise too early?  This is all so confusing compared to what I'm used to!

**Edit6**
All genericCalc does is this:

```
var genericCalc = function (param1, param2, param3) {

    //specific calculation is determined using parameters passed in and varies but is same structure for each as below
    calcPromise = specificCalc(params...);

    impactRemove(currentPrefix, currentArticle); //remove impacts for this prefix

    return calcPromise
       .then(calcsDone)
       .fail(calcsFailed);

    function calcsDone(res) {  
      //some minor subtotalling in here using "res" and flag setting    

      impactAdd(currentPrefix, currentArticle); //addimpacts for this prefix
      return Q.resolve();
    }

    function calcsFailed() {
       //handle error....
    }
};
```

"specificCalc" returns a promise - that one works as I've checked the contents of the promise at a breakpoint. If I remove the calls to "impactRemove" and "impactAdd" above, then "genericCalc" also works. It is those calls that cause the problem.

This is why I think I need something like:

```
impactRemove(params)
    .then(return calcPromise(params)
    .then(impactAdd(params);
```

...but neither impactAdd nor impactRemove do anything asynchronously and I'm also not sure how I can set this up as I need to use params and yet you said those params will mean the functions are immediately invoked...

**Edit 7**

So, as mentioned in the lengthy comments section, this is being caused by a "forEach" loop in genericCalc:

```
var genericCalc = function (calcPrefix, other params...) {
    gcCount++;
    console.log("generic calc starting for: " + calcPrefix + ", count=" + gcCount);
    pGlobalVar.projectIsCalculating(true); //controls spinner gif

    var res_Array = ko.observable(); //holds returned results
    var _prjArticleArray = []; //create local array to use

    if (currentArticle == true) {
        _prjArticleArray.push(pGlobalVar.editProjectArticle());
    } else {
        projectResults().projectArticles().forEach(function (pa) {
            _prjArticleArray.push(pa);
        });
    };

    _prjArticleArray.forEach(function (thisArticle) {

        var calcPromise;

        switch (calcPrefix) {
            case "eol_":
                calcPromise = Q.all([calcEOL(isPackaging, res_Array, thisArticle)]);
                break;
            case "use_":
                calcPromise = Q.all([calcUse(isPackaging, res_Array, thisArticle)]);
                break;
            case "air_":
                calcPromise = Q.all([calcFlight(isPackaging, res_Array, thisArticle)]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        impactRemove(calcPrefix, thisArticle); //remove impacts for this prefix

        return calcPromise
            .then(calcsDone)
            .fail(calcsFailed);

        function calcsDone(args) {

            //do some calcs and totalling based on returned results

            impactAdd(calcPrefix, thisArticle); //add this article impact into project total

            console.log("generic calc done for: " + calcPrefix + ", count=" + gcCount);

            calcTotals(); //accmulates individual results into the "total_xxx" used on the results table and in the chart
            setChart(selectedRow());

            pGlobalVar.projectIsCalculating(false);

        }
        function calcsFailed() {
            logger.logError("Failure in " + calcPrefix + "calculation", "", null, true);
            impactAdd(calcPrefix); //will add back in results as they were at start of calc
            pGlobalVar.projectIsCalculating(false);
        }

    });
};
```

The only reason I've posted it in all its ugly glory is to point out that all works perfectly IF I remove the "forEach" loop and just run this for one article.  Why on earth would the forEach loop make it die a horrible death ?

Comment: In `genericCalc`, the `calcPromise` variable is unintentionally global. Shouldn't cause the issue though.

Comment: What is `rv()`? Is that the function where you have identified the antipattern "*push the result of the ajax calc into a return value*" yourself? Maybe be a little more specific about what you're doing there.

Comment: How are you triggering the `genericCalc()`? You say that it's done by changing some values on the screen. If these handlers are executed quite fast, can it happen that multiple asynchronous recalculations happen at the same time?! That would explain getting the "calcsDone" finish message from the previous run after one of the current "specific calc result" messages. Also by changing the server timing you might prevent this race condition.

Comment: Hi Bergi. I know you're not a fan of how I'm doing this, once I've learned more I will address it!  calcpromise is declared locally in the code I removed for this post, sorry. "rv" is a knockout observable that I set up in genericCalc and it is populated with the ajax calc return value, which is actually an array of 19 numbers!

Comment: I have a knockout observable controlled whether the fields on screen are enabled or disabled. When a value is changed that triggers the recalculation, it also disables all input boxes until the recalculation finishes. Then the fields are re-enabled so it isn't possible to trigger multiple async recalcs.  I set this up because I thought that might be the cause too!  The out-of-sequence debug messages definitely happen in one single recalculation loop.  Most of the time it doesn't happen, occasionally it does. I cannot see what is causing it though.

Comment: Disabling the input boxes might not prevent them from firing events. Install a counter that is increased by a `genericCalc` call and is logged in every of those messages.

Comment: I use breeze.js's "entityAspect.propertyChanged" subscription on the form fields to trigger recalculations: `item.entityAspect.propertyChanged.subscribe(projectArticleChanged);` and this then, depending on which field changed, kicks off a recalculation with specific parameters.  None of the form fields on screen are changed by the values returned from the recalculation.  I have put debug stops in Chrome dev tools on the recalculation routine - it only gets called once.  I also have "console.log" messages all over the place and can see what is being called.  9 times out of 10, it's fine.

Comment: Debug stops can conceal race conditions as well… you should really try the counter. The log you've put in the question is a bit useless, since it doesn't fit to the messages in your example code.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand how to implement the count suggestion you've made, sorry. Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: I meant `var c=0; function genericCalc(){c++; console.log("genericCalc starting "+c); ….then(function{… console.log("genericCalc done "+c); }); }` (maybe also do this for the specific calcs as well). Also, where is that `chart replotted` logged? What [kind of] code is triggered by the observables (which may occur out-of-order)? Is it expected that `specificCalc2` is done twice - for `promiseArray` you're calling only 3 calculations?

Comment: Thanks. Been out all day, sorry.  The specificCalc2 is called twice with different parameters, I removed some of the calls in teh sample code to simplify it.  I put the count in. It massively slows things down and that seems to stop the error happening.  It only ever calls the routines once as expected, no background triggers at all.  Thinking about it, as I can make it hang by stopping the code server-side and resume when I release it, I already know it's correctly waiting for a response, but some race condition seems to kill it occasionally and I don't think I'm ever going to find it.

Comment: Adding a counter to the existing log statements should not have any performance impact. I fear we'll only be able to identify your race condition when you show us the whole code - is it publicly available somewhere?

Comment: No, sorry. Contractually I'm unable to let it be seen due to sensitive company data that is visible on the dev site.

Comment: Added more information at end of OP after "Edit 3" heading. It's a problem with the genericCalc function, it would appear.

Comment: It seems then that `genericCalc` does not always return a promise, but has a path that yields `undefined`. `Q.all` will not fret about that, but just take it as a value. However, the async action with the callback still seems to be started. If you would've use the promise to propagate the values (instead of `res`), you would've noticed that immediately :-)

Comment: hm, "*cannot call method "then" of undefined*" does hint at a problem with (synchronous) control flow within the `genericCalc` function itself - is that `return` in a callback unwittingly? Yes, if `impactRemove` does asynchronous things it should return a promise. Yes, parenthesis will call a function immediately

Comment: `impactRemove` is exactly the same as `impactAdd` up there but it removes values instead of adding them.  It doesn't do it asynchronously and doesn't need to. In fact it needs to have completed BEFORE the ajax call is set off to return the new results and that needs to have completed before `impactAdd` can be called.  I thought that I could do this within the one promise of genericCalc, but it appears not...

Comment: By "the ajax call" you mean the `specificCalc()` request? Maybe you should update the posted `genericCalc` function with those things that you had considered irrelevant before :-)

Comment: Yes, the "specificCalc" request. See edit 6 for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to exchange the order of the `specificCalc()` and `impactRemove()` calls. Even if the first is asynchronous, it will start doing its task *right now* - only the results will arrive in the next turn. If you want to chain anything after a synchronous task, just put it on the next line ("semicolon monad").

Also, if `impactRemove` does assign to your [global (!)](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) variable `calcPromise`, it might not be a promise any more and throw when calling a `.then()` method on it. What you want seems to be

```
function genericCalc(param1, param2, param3) {
    impactRemove(currentPrefix, currentArticle); //remove impacts for this prefix
    return specificCalc(params...).finally(function() {
        impactAdd(currentPrefix, currentArticle); // add impacts for this prefix
    }).then(function calcsDone(res) {  
        // some minor subtotalling in here using "res" and flag setting
        return subtotal;
    }, function calcsFailed() {
        // handle error....
    });
}
```

---

> Why on earth would the forEach loop make it die a horrible death?

Because you're not returning a promise. A `forEach` loop has its own callback, from which you can `return`, but from the `genericCalc` function nothing is returned. `Q.all` will not fret about that, but just take the `undefined` as a value. However, the async action is to be started and you get your callbacks, but `Q.all` won't wait for it, because it does not know of it.

The solution is a quite simple change and has already been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22070033/1048572).

Comment: `obect has no method 'finally'` - on the `return specificCalc(params...).finally(...` line.  It seems to be a promise on inspection as it has "then" and "always" and "done", etc.  Should I be using "done" instead of "finally"?

Comment: [It should have](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-promisefinallycallback). Are you using an old version, or is this a non-Q promise maybe? `.always` sounds right, though.

Comment: It has the following properties: `always, done, fail, pipe, progress, promise, state, then and proto`  I just updated Q to v. 1.0.0 from 0.9.6 and it's made no difference.

Comment: That's a jQuery promise. Wrap it in `Q()` before returning from `specificCalc`, or use `.always()` which should do the same as `.finally()`

Comment: Hmm. The cause of the problem is the "forEach" I have in my genericCalc. It's still a problem if I use "map" though, so that doesn't help.  As a project can have many articles, sometimes I have to iterate through each article performing the same set of calculations. I have this "forEach" loop and within it I declare the promise and call the specific calculations. If I just remove the array code and do a single article, it all works peachily (even with my old code...) but as soon as I put the "forEach" or a "map" in there, it all breaks horribly.  Will update OP with simplified layout to show.

Comment: Edit 7 in OP now contains more details.

Comment: Ah, the reason, at last!

Comment: Hallelujah! I understand now. This is so fraught with pitfalls for beginners like me.  How on earth do you get to learn about all the different callbacks that are lurking - like with the "forEach" loop?  Is it just a case of learning with experience that some methods/functions come with a callback and some don't or do ALL methods/functions come with a callback?

Comment: No, most function do not have callbacks. See also [Are all Node.js callback functions asynchronous?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21884258/1048572)